# Problems in performing K means clustering

Tags: python, list, numpy, scipy, k-means

I am trying to cluster the following data from a CSV file with K means clustering.

```
Sample1,Sample2,45
Sample1,Sample3,69
Sample1,Sample4,12
Sample2,Sample2,46
Sample2,Sample1,78
```

It is basically a graph where Samples are nodes and the numbers are the edges (weights).

I read the file as following:

```
fileopening = fopen('data.csv', 'rU')
reading = csv.reader(fileopening, delimiter=',')

L = list(reading)
```

I used this code: https://gist.github.com/betzerra/8744068

Here clusters are built based on the following:

```
num_points, dim, k, cutoff, lower, upper = 10, 2, 3, 0.5, 0, 200
points = map( lambda i: makeRandomPoint(dim, lower, upper), range(num_points) )
clusters = kmeans(points, k, cutoff)

for i,c in enumerate(clusters): 
    for p in c.points:
        print " Cluster: ",i,"\t Point :", p
```

I replaced points with list L. But I got lots of errors: `AttributeError, 'int' object has no attribute 'n'`, etc.

I need to perform K means clustering based on the third number column (edges) of my CSV file. This tutorial uses randomly creating points.  But I am not sure, how to use this CSV data as an input to this k means function. How to perform k means (k=2) for my data? How can I send the CSV file data as input to this k means function?

Comment: Your first problem is that the library you are trying to use requires coordinate points, but your data only shows distance between points. Is your data two-dimensional? three-dimensional?

Comment: @AndrewJohnson No. It is just one dimensional... third row displays the distance between points A and B.

Comment: If it is one-dimensional, then you can just pick a point, say `Sample1` to be zero, and calculate the absolute location of every other point relative to that. Then this library will work for kmeans. Edit: you still can't tell whether something is greater than or less than that point on the number line, so no this won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lejlot said, only distances between points are not enough to run k-means in the classic sense. It's easy to understand if you understand the nature of k-means. On a high level, k-means works as follows:

```
1) Randomly assign points to cluster.
  (Technically, there are more sophisticated ways of initial  partitioning, 
  but that's not essential right now).

2) Compute centroids of the cluster. 
  (This is where you need the actual coordinates of the points.)

3) Reassign each point to a cluster with the closest centroid.

4) Repeat steps 2)-3) until stop condition is met.
```

So, as you can see, in the classic interpretation, k-means will not work, because it is unclear how to compute centroids. However, I have several suggestions of what you could do.

**Suggestion 1.**

Embed your points in N-dimensional space, where N is the number of points, so that the coordinates of each point are the distances to all the other points.

For example the data you showed:

```
Sample1,Sample2,45
Sample1,Sample3,69
Sample1,Sample4,12
Sample2,Sample2,46
Sample2,Sample1,78
```

becomes:

```
Sample1: (0,45,69,12,...)
Sample2: (78,46,0,0,...)
```

Then you can legitimately use Euclidean distance. Note, that the actual distances between points will not be preserved, but this could be a simple and reasonable approximation to preserve relative distances between the points. Another disadvantage is that if you have a lot of points, than your memory (and running time) requirements will be order of N^2.

**Suggestion 2.**

Instead of k-means, try k-medoids. For this one, you do not need the actual coordinates of the points, because instead of centroid, you need to compute medoids. Medoid of a cluster is a points from this cluster, whish has the smallest average distance to all other points in this cluster. You could look for the implementations online. Or it's actually pretty easy to implement. The running time will be proportional to N^2 as well.

**Final remark.**

Why do you wan to use k-means at all? Seems like you have a weighted directed graph. There are clustering algorithms specially intended for graphs. This is beyond the scope of your question, but maybe this is something that could be worth considering?

Comment: i think you are right. But I m not able to find any code for clustering the weighted graphs?

Answer (score 2):

In short "you can't".

Long answer:
K-means is defined for **euclidean spaces only** and it requires a valid **points positions**, while you only have distances between them, probably not in a strict mathematical sense but rather some kind of "similarity". K-means is not designed to work with similarity matrices.

What you can do?

1. You can use some other method to embeed your points in euclidean space in such a way, that they closely reasamble your distances, one of such tools is Multidimensional scaling (MDS): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling
2. Once point 1 is done you can run k-means

Alternatively you can also construct a kernel (valid in a Mercer's sense) by performing some kernel learning techniques to reasamble your data and then run kernel k-means on the resulting Gram matrix.